# How to get Order status in Bittrex API

Tags: exchange-order, bittrex

How to know what is the order status when using `getOrder` API?

request:

```
https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/account/getorder&uuid=<uuid>
```

Example response:

```
{
"success" : true,
"message" : "",
"result" : {
    "AccountId" : null,
    "OrderUuid" : "0cb4c4e4-bdc7-4e13-8c13-430e587d2cc1",
    "Exchange" : "BTC-SHLD",
    "Type" : "LIMIT_BUY",
    "Quantity" : 1000.00000000,
    "QuantityRemaining" : 1000.00000000,
    "Limit" : 0.00000001,
    "Reserved" : 0.00001000,
    "ReserveRemaining" : 0.00001000,
    "CommissionReserved" : 0.00000002,
    "CommissionReserveRemaining" : 0.00000002,
    "CommissionPaid" : 0.00000000,
    "Price" : 0.00000000,
    "PricePerUnit" : null,
    "Opened" : "2014-07-13T07:45:46.27",
    "Closed" : null,
    "IsOpen" : true,
    "Sentinel" : "6c454604-22e2-4fb4-892e-179eede20972",
    "CancelInitiated" : false,
    "ImmediateOrCancel" : false,
    "IsConditional" : false,
    "Condition" : "NONE",
    "ConditionTarget" : null
}}
```

Comment: Do you mean like if the order is open or close? "Closed" : null, "IsOpen" : true . Or something more specific?

Comment: The documentation are not clear what are the states (open, closed, etc) and how it reflect in the response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this field from response json to know if order is filled

```
QuantityRemaining
```

And this filed tells if order is open or close

```
IsOpen
```

Its pretty self-explanatory. Comment if you wish to know more things.